# Error executing bleachbit as root

Tags: bleachbit

I got this error:

```
(bleachbit:5510): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/niider/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

Comment: This is not an error.

Comment: When you want to run a graphical application as root, use `sudo -H bleachbit` to avoid such warnings

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error. It is just a warning related to using sudo. If IBUS (input method for multilingual input) is working, then do not worry about it.

The interpretation is that you are running as root but accessing niider's file. This is a mismatch. Again, this may be harmless.

For BleachBit 2.0 (alpha due soon) I am using pkexec instead of sudo, so that may help.